# Combinatorics (Number Question)

Tags: combinatorics

How many ten-digit numbers only composed of 1, 2 and 3 exist, in which any two neighboring digits differ by 1?

While answering please also share your motivation! Thank you

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!. When asking a question here, it is customary to write your own motivation for wanting the problem solved. Don't worry, we help people with their homework here all the time. Also, if you try to explain what you have tried, where you're stuck and what you _do_ understand, then it's much easier for us to write an answer that actually teaches you something rather than just give you the answer. Most of the people answering questions here prefer to teach people to fish rather than giving them a fish from day to day.

Comment: Quite a lot. I think that the *number* of digits must be one of the data here.

Comment: I'm sorry, i would've shared my progress - if i had made any! I really have to idea how to approach this. I tried making numbers where adjacent digits differed by one but they were way too many. I had no idea how to make sure that i'd covered all possibilities, or what all of the possibilities were. And no, this is not homework!

Comment: Fair enough, but it never hurts to *say so* in your post!

Answer (score 1):

If the first is 1, the second has to be 2, the third 1 or 3, the fourth 2, the fifth 1 or 3 etc. If the first is 2, then the second is 1 or 3, the third 2, the fourth 1 or 3, etc.

Case I. Odd ones 2, even ones 1 or 3: $2\times 2\times 2 \times 2 \times 2=2^5$ cases.

Case II. Even ones 2, odd ones 1 or 3: $2\times 2\times 2 \times 2 \times 2=2^5$ cases.

Altogether: $2^6$ ways.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!